# Black screen during boot, but image at log-in. 760 cards SLI setup

Tags: boot, sli

I've got two 760 cards in SLI, and during boot of my computer there is no image, so I can't access BIOS or other services. Now, the image will come once the PC has booted, and there is no other issues after that.

I've tried the following: Booting up with monitor connected to every available plug, on both cards and on the motherboard, and update drivers to newest. I can't roll back, tho, due to older drivers will not work with BF4...

Some google searches suggest that I set some graphics options in BIOS to be PCIE, but this was done to even have the SLI working from day one. I remember it well as I had an outdated BIOS firmware that did not support my CPU.

Is there a way I can see BIOS with an SLI setup, or do I need to rip out a card (or both) every time I need BIOS access? I work with IT, tho this is my first SLI build, so kinda fumbling in the dark here.

Ah, and specs:

- Windows 7 64 bit enterprise (yarr...)
- 2x Asus 760 cards in SLI
- 16 GB RAM
- Intel i7-3770 CPU
- Asus P8Z68-V PRO GEN3 Motherboard
- 700 GB HDD
- 240x2 SSD in JBOD

Comment: If you do roll back does it work though?

Comment: Nope, that did not work...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my method:

- Remove the graphic driver by using "revo uninstaller", this is going to put your Pc on sleep; then you can not do anything afterward, but don't panic.
- Force power off your pc (hold your power button), then unplug the SLi bridge, switch your DP/HDMI cable into the second card.
- The next step is power on your PC, now you can see your starting screen as normal.
- Try to do "perform a clean install" your graphic driver again, After finishing it will ask you to restart the PC, hit the restart button
- During the starting screen, quickly replug the SLI bridge back to the first card (by this way the motherboard will regconize your first card).
- Now enter the "NVIDIA control panel" select "Maximum 3D performance" then click "Apply".
- Restart your PC again.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate SLI/Plug SLI Bridge out and enter BIOS with only one Card. Check if the BIOS has any Options to set default output on boot. The Motherboard/GPU is probably looking which port is responding first but your monitor is connected to something else. By that time post is over and it boots.